# "this" in react higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to move shared functionality from my react components to a higher order component like this:

```
function withListFunctions(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        // my shared functionality
        deleteItem() {
            // Do something, then ...
            this.setState({itemDeleted: true});
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
                 />
            );
        }
    }
```

Using this kind of syntax requires to explicitely bind `this` in the constructor of the HOC:

```
this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
```

.. but I wanted to bind the wrapped component instead. So what I tried in my wrapped component's constructor was

```
this.props.deleteItem = this.props.deleteItem.bind(this);
```

But this just resulted in a "Cannot assign to read only property" Error, as react props are meant to be read only.

I am aware that I could store the state item in the HOC and pass it down as a prop. But it would then be not accessible(writeable) anymore by other wrapped components functions, right? I wonder if there is a way to just share the unbound function and then bind it to the wrapped instance.

**[Edit]** I marked Abdul Rauf's answer as "accepted", nevertheless I want to state that Karen Grigoryan's answer is the solution I am actually using because it works and seems just appropiate for my app's complexity.

Comment: Note sure if this will work, but have you tried this? `this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(WrappedComponent)`

Comment: @PatrickHund your solution binds to the class not to the instance

Comment: You're right, that doesn't work

Comment: Although React favours composition over inheritance, you can still use inheritance if it make sense.  If you want to create a wrapped component without inheritance, I would pass the component to be wrapped as a prop.

Comment: "But it would then be not accessible(writeable) anymore by other wrapped components functions, right?" no, it will be writeable if you pass prop like `setDeletedItem={this.setDeletedItem}` into `<WrappedComponent ...`. But it looks like breaking encapsulation. do you really need to change `deletedItem` from the inside of `WrappedComponent`?

Comment: @Keith yes, I had regular inheritance in mind, but I had also some experiences with unflexible inheritance chains in PHP, so I tried to follow the "composition over inheritance" advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am aware that I could store the state item in the HOC and pass it
>   down as a prop. But it would then be not accessible(writeable) anymore
>   by other wrapped components functions, right?

You should store shared state in HOC. You can pass multiple state update methods to Wrapped components that they can call internally to update state indirectly.

If you don't want to pass multiple state update methods then we have 2 options:

**Option 1:** Create a single `dispatch` method in HOC that takes `action` and optional `payload` and pass it to Wrapped components.

```
// Do not mutate state in reducer. always return a new state
reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'delete':
      // return final state after delete
    case 'add':
      // return final state after add using action.payload
    case 'update':
      // return final state after update using action.payload
    default:
      // A reducer must always return a valid state.
      // Alternatively you can throw an error if an invalid action is dispatched.
      return state;
  }
}


dispatch(action) {
    const updatedState = this.reducer(this.state, action)
    this.setState(updatedState);
}
```

**Option 2:** Use [`useReducer` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) if you can use latest react with hooks support.

> I wonder if there is a way to just share the unbound function and then
>   bind it to the wrapped instance.

Technically you can do that ([Check Karen Grigoryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53466830/2073920)). But it is considered a bad practice because of many reasons. Few of those are:

1. Its against encapsulation principles. (State is in Child component and state update logic is in parent component). Parent component shouldn't know anything about state of child components.
2. Props can change over time but this won't be reflected automatically in derived `Instance properties/fields`

Comment: Could you concretize in a few words why Karen Grigoryans answer is considered a bad practice? Does it have concrete drawbacks, or does it just not follow the framework's opinion how things should be structured?

Answer (score 2):

`props` are read only by [design](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element).

> React elements are immutable. Once you create an element, you can’t change its children or attributes. An element is like a single frame in a movie: it represents the UI at a certain point in time.

So technically one of the ways to bind `deleteItem` to `WrappedComponent` context, is to just `bind` it in `WrappedComponent` `constructor`:

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3k2qw90xw)

`this.deleteItem = this.props.deleteItem.bind(this);`